# How do you replace multiple things at once using regex replace function? Is it possible? Trying to learn regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Clearly it's only replacing the last thing which is i. Is there a way to do this all at once under multiple conditions? The function should replace all letter a with 4, letter e with 3, letter i with 1, letter o with 0, and letter s with 5.

```
function hackerSpeak(str) { 
  return str.replace(/a/ig, 4) && str.replace(/e/ig, 3) && str.replace(/i/ig, 1) && str.replace(/o/ig, 0) && str.replace(/s/ig, 5);
}

console.log(hackerSpeak("javascript is cool")); //"j4v45cr1pt 15 c00l"
```

Comment: Please, use code tag for code part to properly format your post.

Comment: What is the actual output? Keep in mind that the && will usually stop executing if it returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- TLDR; here's a solution:

```js
function hackerSpeak(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/a/gi, 4)
    .replace(/e/gi, 3)
    .replace(/i/gi, 1)
    .replace(/o/gi, 0)
    .replace(/s/gi, 5);
}
```

- **Expalanation:**

The `String.prototype.replace` method is a pure function, meaning it produces a new string each time you call it and leaves the original string intact (which is immutable in js anyway). The `a && b` operator evaluates to `b` if `a` is "truthy", so when you say `str.replace(...) && str.replace(...)`, only the part on the right gets returned (given the first one didn't result in an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Bind replaces
const hackerSpeak = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/a/ig, 4).replace(/e/ig, 3).replace(/i/ig, 1).replace(/o/ig, 0).replace(/s/ig, 5);
}

// Demo
console.log(hackerSpeak("javascript is cool")); //"j4v45cr1pt 15 c00l"
```

```js
// Or use object library
const hackerSpeak = (str) => {
  // Set your library
  const lib = {
    a: 4,
    e: 3,
    i: 1,
    o: 0,
    s: 5
  };
  
  // Apply RegExp's in loop
  Object.keys(lib).forEach(k => str = str.replace(new RegExp(k, 'gi'), lib[k]));
  return str;
}

// Demo
console.log(hackerSpeak("javascript is cool")); //"j4v45cr1pt 15 c00l"
```

```js
// Or use just one RegExp
const hackerSpeak = str => str.replace(/([aeios])/ig, m => ({ a:4, e:3, i:1, o:0, s:5 })[m]);

// Demo
console.log(hackerSpeak("javascript is cool")); //"j4v45cr1pt 15 c00l"
```

JavaScript really cool)

Answer (score 0):

Used an object for a more dynamic approach.

```js
const toReplaceWith = {
  a: 4,
  s: 5,
  i: 1,
  o: 0
}

function hackerSpeak(str){ 
  Object.keys(toReplaceWith).forEach(letter => str = str.replaceAll(new RegExp(letter, 'gi'), toReplaceWith[letter]));
  
  return str;
}

console.log(hackerSpeak("javascript is cool")); //"j4v45cr1pt 15 c00l"
```